# Selenium: NoAlertPresentException

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to automate a test that includes logging in via a Authentication Required popup alert. When it execute either either of the lines:

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent());
IAlert alert = PropertiesCollections.driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
```

a NoAlertPresentException is thrown.  I can use the http://username:password@site.com url format, although it logs me in, it doesn't load the entire page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using AutoIT, to enter username/Password. That window is windows modal and that's the reason it throws NoAlertPresentException.